# ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'. Message: ' Internal error: spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed

Tags: php, push-notification, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to subscribe a user for push notifications. These are headers that contains a valid access token.

```
> POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions
> Authorization: Bearer *** access token ***
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
```

The body of the request is:

```
> {
>     "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
>     "Resource":"https:\/\/outlook.office.com\/api\/v2.0\/me\/events",
>     "NotificationURL":"https:\/\/myapp.com",
>     "ChangeType":"Updated"
> }
```

The response is always

```
< HTTP/1.1 401
< {
<     "error": {
<         "code": "InvalidMsaTicket",
<         "message": "ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'. Message: ' Internal error: spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed. Failed to call CRPSDataCryptImpl::UnpackData: Internal error: Failed to decrypt data. :Failed to get session key. RecipientId=293577. spCache->GetCacheItem returns error.:Cert Name: (null). SKI: 3bd72187c709b1c40b994f8b496a5b9ebd2f9b0c...'",
<         "innerError": {
<             "requestId": "e99fd47a-763f-4cf4-9b12-31e62c57fbe4",
<             "date": "2020-02-04T09:30:13"
<         }
<     }
< }
```

It seems that Outlook cant find a certificate? I cant find an outlook's error page list to detect what is the problem here. Could someone help to understand this error and get right way to register the user to push notifications?